# "IndexError: Index X is out of bounds" generated when converting 3.X python script to 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I have a script I wrote for 3.X that runs great, however I needed to convert it to 2.7 and while doing so came across this error I don't know how to solve.

This function corrects data by dividing it into periods and finding a percentile for each period to apply to said data.

```
import numpy
import math
import random
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.layouts import *
from __future__ import division

def rs_percent_corr(start, end, rs, rso, thresh, period):

num_periods = int(math.ceil((end - start) / period))
rs_period = numpy.zeros(period)
rso_period = numpy.zeros(period)
period_corr = numpy.zeros(num_periods)

# Placing intervals in separate array for easy handling
rs_interval = numpy.array(rs[start:end])
rso_interval = numpy.array(rso[start:end])

# separate the interval into predefined periods and compute correction
count_one = 0  # index for full correction interval
count_two = 0  # index for within each period
count_three = 0  # index for number of periods
while count_one < len(rs_interval):
    if (count_two < period) and count_one == len(rs_interval) - 1:
        # if statement handles final period
        rs_period[count_two] = rs_interval[count_one]
        rso_period[count_two] = rso_interval[count_one]
        count_one += 1
        count_two += 1
        while count_two < period:
            # This fills out the rest of the final period with NaNs so
            # they are not impacted by the remaining zeros
            rs_period[count_two] = numpy.nan
            rso_period[count_two] = numpy.nan
            count_two += 1

        ratio = numpy.divide(rs_period, rso_period)
        period_corr[count_three] = numpy.nanpercentile(ratio, thresh)

    elif count_two < period:
        # haven't run out of data points, and period still hasn't been filled
        rs_period[count_two] = rs_interval[count_one]
        rso_period[count_two] = rso_interval[count_one]
        count_one += 1
        count_two += 1
    else:
        # end of a period
        count_two = 0
        ratio = numpy.divide(rs_period, rso_period)
        period_corr[count_three] = numpy.nanpercentile(ratio, thresh)
        count_three += 1

return period_corr
```

When running the script in 3.X it works, but trying to run it in 2.7 generates "IndexError: Index 110 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 110" on the line `period_corr[count_three] = numpy.nanpercentile(ratio, thresh)`

What am I missing? Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the full traceback?

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is the line `num_periods = int(math.ceil((end - start) / period))`.

In Python 3 `/` is true division. `3 / 2` will return `1.5`. In Python 2 this is not the case, `/` performs integer division so `3/2` will return `1`.

If you need to support both versions in the same time, you can insert `from __future__ import division` *in the first line of your script*, then Python 2 `/` will behave like Python 3's.

Comment: I just noticed that OP already uses `from __future__ import division` ...

Comment: You're correct, but the funny thing is I had the future import line already, but the reason it was was giving me the error anyways was due to the fact that the script I was running wasn't the version of the script with that line, so my real problem was version/workspace management! Thank you for the assistance.

The real tipoff that I wasn't running the correct script should have been the fact that I didn't get a SyntaxError that from __future__ import division needed to be at the start of the file.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I suspect OP added it after the fact, since `__future__` import must be the first `import` otherwise it is a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @SolIV Also see my above comment

Comment: @SolIV maybe you should edit your question to show the actual script, not the one with the buggy "from future" import, because it misled us.